# Finding density function

Tags: probability-distributions

Let Y have a uniform distribution on interval (0,1)

Find the density function of U=1-Y^2

I cant graph this, and transformation don't work .
Anyone give me a hint on this one?

I worked out the density to be 1/(4(1-x)^(3/2))
what kind of density is this?

Comment: You can't graph $y=1-x^2$?

Comment: I mean like , how would i calculate the area of that afterwards?

Comment: "what kind of density is this?" Not a density, to begin with. Did you read the answer posted below?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\mathbb R$. Then
$$\{U\leqslant x\} = \{1-Y^2 \leqslant x\} = \{Y^2 \geqslant 1-x\}=\{Y^2>1-x\}\cup\{Y^2=1-x\} $$
and $\mathbb P\{Y^2 = 1-x\}=0$ since $Y$ is a continuous random variable. So
$$\mathbb P\{U\leqslant x\} = 1 - \mathbb P\{Y^2\leqslant 1-x\}.$$
If $x\leqslant 0$, then $1-x\geqslant 1$, so $\mathbb P\{Y^2\leqslant 1-x \}=1$ (as $Y^2(\omega)>1$ iff $|Y(\omega)|>1$). If $x\geqslant1$ then $1-x<0$ so $\mathbb P\{Y^2\leqslant 1-x\}=0$. For $0<x<1$, $\mathbb P\{Y^2\leqslant 1-x\} = \mathbb P\{Y\leqslant\sqrt{1-x}\}$. Hence the distribution function of $U$ is

$$ F(x) = \mathbb P\{U\leqslant x\} =
\begin{cases}
0,& x \leqslant 0\\
1-\sqrt{1-x},& 0<x<1\\
1,& x \geqslant 1.\\
\end{cases}$$

The density is obtained by differentiating the distribution function:

$$f(x) =\frac1{2\sqrt{1-x}}, 0<x<1. $$